# C# Pass string to method from foreach loop

Tags: c#, parameters, foreach

I am trying to call a method from a `foreach` loop on each iteration and pass the string that is updated on each iteration to the method. How can I get the method I am calling to take the string?

Here is what I am testing:

```
foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
{
    string url = "http://www.amazon.com/gp/offer-listing/"+dr["ASIN"].ToString();
    updatedatabase(url);
}
```

Using this method:

```
private void updatedatabase(url) 
{
    MessageBox.Show(url);
}
```

Comment: What is the problem with your current code? What happens when you compile it? What is the error message?

Comment: It says "the name url does not exist in the current context."  This is in the updatedatabase method.

Comment: can you post the whole code block?  This makes it look as if you are trying to declare a method inside of the body of another method (since the `updatedatabase` method appears to be a peer of your for loop)

Comment: After you edited the question the answers that have already been posted no longer make sense.

Comment: Agreed! I accepted the changes so it makes sense now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One problem would be that you did not specify the type of the argument to your method.  You could try this:

```
private void updatedatabase( String url ) {
    MessageBox.Show( url );
}
```

Comment: Yep.  That's exactly what I just figured out.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: @reg, mark one of these as the answer so that the next guy coming around can benefit from your experience.

Comment: Yep I did.  Appriciate the help.

Answer (score 5):

You need to add the type (`string`) to the method definition:

```
private void updatedatabase(string url)
{
    MessageBox.Show(url);
}
```

Sidenote: I would also recommend that you use Pascal case for your method names.

- [Capitalization Conventions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229043.aspx)